# irb terminates with no method error

Tags: ruby, irb

When I input the following lines in irb, the irb terminates.

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> def !; end
=> :!
irb(main):002:0> !
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/input-method.rb:153:in `gets': private method `!' called for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
...
$
```

Leaving aside the question of whether defining or calling a method named `!` is valid or not, I suppose irb should not quit even when an error is raised. Is this a bug? Do you know what causes this?

Comment: Just made a bug report: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10184.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code in a file:

```
def !;
  puts "Hi"
end

send(:!)

!();
```

Ruby (1.9.3) gives this:

```
Hi
testexclaim.rb:7:in `<main>': private method `!' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

In my 1.9.3 IRB, it seems to be interpreting the ! as the not operator, even with parenthesis.

It seems to me that because `send` works, this is more of a parsing bug than anything else that neither IRB nor Ruby can handle.

Comment: Thanks, I just posted a bug report to ruby trunk, as linked in the comment above.

Comment: @sawa: OK. I'm not sure anyone will consider it important to fix though - if real code names something !, they have bigger problems.

Comment: Its either they should prohibit such name, or work correctly. It may have low priority like you say. But it still should be fixed.

Comment: Actually, in Ruby 2, method `!` is negation, and it is public.

Comment: @sawa: Oh! I didn't realize that they made that overridable.

Comment: in Ruby `!` negation operator and avaliable in any `Object`.  `self.send("!")`. `methods.grep(/^!$/)` => `!() Object (BasicObject)`